# Multi master replication with different database

Tags: mysql

I have three database server.

1. ip=192.168.1.101 db=google
2. ip=192.168.1.102 db1=google db2=yahoo
3. ip=192.168.1.103 db1=google db2=yahoo

I want to do master replication between server1 and server2 for db=google
and
master master replication between server2 and server3 for db=yahoo

Can I have a suggestion or reference links to do that?

Comment: It would be simpler to simply have all servers contain the same datasets.  Can you justify this departure from the norm?

Comment: Yes, if i do replication all dbs on all server then it will be simple.
But I don't want to replicate yahoo db on server1.
Is there any way to achieve above flow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have M1 -> M2 -> M3 -> M1  ?

On M1, have the tables in `yahoo` be `ENGINE=BLACKHOLE`.